# SAS: sum over subset of a table column (multiple times)

Tags: sas

(I'm new to SAS, and I struggle with how involved it is to do stuff column-wise which would be quite easy in a "normal" language. Please bear with me if this is extremely basic.)

I have a table with values *type*, *a1-a10* and *b1-b10*, and I would like to find (for each *N*) the sum of *bN* for those rows where *aN* is positive. I can do it one variable at a time, e.g. with something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table work.test1 as
    select type, b1
    from work.table
    where (a1 >0);
run;
```

and then sum over all those tables and then merge them, but that's going to be a lot of code and a bit of a faff. Is there a nice and compact way to do this?

Edit: The output I'd like is a table with values *type*, *sum1-sum10*, where *sumN* is the sum described above.

Sample data:

```
type | a1 | a2 | ... | b1 | b2 | ...
------------------------------------
 cat   10   14   ...   1     2   ...
 cat   -5    3   ...   1     1   ...
 dog   35   -1   ...   9     3   ...
 dog    9    2   ...  0.5    1   ...
```

Desired output:

```
type | sum1 | sum2 | ...
------------------------
 cat    1      3     ...
 dog   9.5     1     ...
```

So for each *type* and *N* sums those *bN* where the *aN* on the same row is positive.

Comment: Do you want each output to be in a different tables e.g test1, test2 etc.?

Comment: No, I'd like one table with variables type, sum1, sum2, etc.

Comment: Can you add a sample data? Do you want the sum to be done within each type?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the sum by type. I'll add some sample data.

Comment: I stuck with your initial idea. There are other ways of solving the problem. Let me know if that does it for you.

Comment: To be honest, "other ways" are probably better. My initial idea was more of a "this is probably not a good plan", so if there is a way do to it that doesn't go by way of lots of extra throwaway tables that would be better.

Comment: I can get what I want by adding auxiliary variables to each row, e.g. "if (aN >0) then auxN = bN; else auxN=0;" and then making the desired table via a 'proc means' (with "sum(auxN) = sumN"), but that's ugly and wasteful; I was really hoping for some way to get it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single `SQL` `select` with one `case` clause for each variable.

**Data**

```
data have; input 
type $ a1   a2   b1  b2  ; datalines;
cat    10   14   1    2
cat    -5    3   1    1
dog    35   -1   9    3
dog     9    2   0.5  1
run;
```

**SQL Example**

```
proc sql;
  create table want_way1
  as select 
    type
  , sum (case when a1 > 0 then b1 else 0 end) as sum1
  , sum (case when a2 > 0 then b2 else 0 end) as sum2
  from have
  group by type
  ;
```

SQL does not have arrays, so a macro would be written to generate either the entire SQL or only the needed clauses for each of the *N* `a` and `b` variable pairs.  The macro can examine the data's metadata if you wanted to the macro to discover *N* itself.

**DATA Step example**

Using DOW loop for group processing and arrays for item processing. Quite compact if you remove the comments.

```
data want_way2 (keep=type sum:);
  do until (last.type);
    set have;
    by type;

    * array statement is non-executable, but associates PDV variables with the array reference;
    * array statement will create new variables in PDV if needed;

    array a a1-a2;      /* connects existing variables with array */
    array b b1-b2;      /* connects existing variables with array */
    array s sum1-sum2;  /* creates new variables and connects them with array */

    * repurpose _n_ as simply an automatic variable that does not need to be dropped;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(a);
      s(_n_) = sum ( s(_n_) , ifn ( a(_n_) > 0, b(_n_), 0 ) );
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: The DOW example relies on tacit automatic actions of the `DATA` step implicit loop. Use with caution if adding that example into your coding bag of tricks.

Comment: Yeah, I find that kind of trickery is way above my level; I don't like doing things I don't understand fully. I prefer the SQL example, that is more or less what I was trying to do in the first place, but didn't know how.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `proc summary` approach. This isn't quite as direct as the array approach, but it's much easier to generalise to other statistics that might interest you.

```
data have; 
input type $ a1   a2   b1  b2  ; 
datalines;
cat    10   14   1    2
cat    -5    3   1    1
dog    35   -1   9    3
dog     9    2   0.5  1
;
run;

/*Create a view of the dataset with suitable weight columns*/
data t_have / view = t_have;
  set have;
  array a[*] a1-a2;
  do i = 1 to dim(a);
    a[i] = a[i] > 0;
  end;
run;

/*Use proc summary to sum across rows*/
proc summary nway data = t_have;
  class type;
  var b1 /weight=a1; /*You could macro-ise this bit to avoid excessive repetition*/
  var b2 /weight=a2;
  output out= want(drop=_:) sum= mean= /autoname;
run;
```

Comment: Good example of the features of PROC means/summary.  But I reckon you already know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrays to perform this task in a single step, with a single output.  An array stores values across columns in memory, which can then be looped through to do the calculations.

In this code, I've created 3 arrays, one for A1-A2, one for B1-B2 and one for the new variables SUM1-Sum2.  Obviously in your real data you would change the range to A10, B10, SUM10.

I've added a load of comments to describe what the code is doing, but I also recommend reading up on arrays to get a better understanding.

```
/* create input data */
data have;
input type $ a1 a2 b1 b2;
datalines;
cat . 14 1 2
cat -5 3 1 1
dog 35 -1 9 3
dog 9 2 0.5 1
;
run;

/* sort data by type (needed for next step) */
proc sort data=have;
by type;
run;

data want;
set have;
by type; /* data neds to be sorted by this */
array var_a{2} a1-a2; /* store the values of a in an array */
array var_b{2} b1-b2; /* store the values of b in an array */
array sumvar{2} sum1-sum2; /* set up an array of sum variables (will also create physical variables) */
if first.type then do; /* set sum variables to zero when type changes */
    do i = 1 to dim(sumvar);
        sumvar{i} = 0;
    end;
end;
do j=1 to dim(var_a); /* loop through each var_a value and add var_b to sum_N if var_a>0 */
    if var_a{j}>0 then sumvar{j}+var_b{j}; /* syntax var1 + var2 retains value across rows */
end;
keep type sum: ; /* only keep required variables */
if last.type then output; /* only output last record for each type, with the total sum */
run;
```

Comment: Amended code to reset initial value of SUM_N variables to 0 instead of missing.  Therefore if no VAR_A values are positive then the sum will show as 0

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want then I think putting your code in a macro would do the trick. For example in the one below, I use a `%do` loop to generate 10 different datasets, one for each `N`. All I did was wrap your code up in a macro so I'm hoping your code does what you want already. And I replaced your `run` by `quit` otherwise `proc sql` won't stop.

Edit:

```
options symbolgen mprint mlogic;

%macro Y(N=);

  %macro compute;
  %do i = 1 %to &N.;
    proc sql;
      create table work.test&i. as
        select type, sum(b&i.) as sum&i.
        from work.table
        where (a&i. >0)
        group by type
        order by type;
      quit;
   %end;
  %mend;

   %compute;

      data want;
      %do i = 1 %to &N.;
        merge test&i.;
      %end;
      run;
 %mend;

%Y(N=10);
```

Comment: This seems to work, except it fails if there are some missing values (my actual _aN_ are often zero, so I guess the sum becomes '.' if none are positive?), is there a way around this? I don't quite understand how the sum() function handles missing values.

Comment: @KetilTveiten look at the documentation for the SUM function to see how it handles missing values.